# with Makefile create folders from specific filenames

Tags: bash, makefile

I need a Makefile that create for every `<file.rst>` a `<file>` folder to then execute
hovercraft on the `<file.rst>` which need a folder as second argument

```bash
    $ tree                                                                                          
    .                                                                                               
    ├── a.rst                                                                                       
    ├── b.rst                                                                                       
    └── Makefile
```

With this Makefile

```bash
    $ cat Makefile                                                                                  
    .PHONY: html   
                                                                               
    HTML_TARGETS:= $(patsubst %.rst,%.html,$(wildcard *.rst))                                       
                                                                                                    
    html: $(HTML_TARGETS)                                                                           
                                                                                                    
    %.html: %.rst                                                                                   
        @rm -fr $(basename $@ .html)                                                                
        @mkdir -p $(basename $@ .html)                                                              
        @hovercraft -Ns $< $(basename $@ .html)                                                     
    $
```

It kind of works

```
.
├── a
│   └── index.html
├── a.rst
├── b
│   └── index.html
├── b.rst
└── Makefile
```

I fell how baroquish this Makefile is, what could be a better way to write it ?

BTW I fail to add in the Makefile this echo:

```
@echo output done in $(basename $@ .html)/index.html
```

I get:

```
 output done in a /index.html                                                                   
 output done in b /index.html                                                                   
                 ^                                                                              
                 └─ with an unwanted space
```

I whould like to print:

```
 output done in a/index.html                                                                    
 output done in b/index.html
```

Comment: As I said in your other question, `$(basename $@ .html)` does **not** do what you think.  Please see the GNU make manual to learn how it actually works, then you will see where the extra space comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly that you want to make a directory "x", then execute `hovercraft x.rst x/index.html` for every file "x.rst", then this should be a succinct way to do so.

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard *.rst)
TARGETS := $(SOURCES:.rst=/index.html)

%/index.html: %.rst
    mkdir -p $*
    hovercraft $< $@

.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGETS)
```

Comment: Please don't recommend adding `@` before recipe lines to hide the output.  That output is critical for knowing how make is working.

Comment: That's actually great advice. The reason it was there, was because I use it with `echo` in front of commands just to verify the target works as expected without doing any real work and without printing the command twice. Then I just remove the echo's, but didn't remove this for some reason. Anyway, aside from `@echo` they really are counterproductive.